# Why my ubuntu only boots when acpi=off?

Tags: boot, grub2, acpi

My ubuntu machine does not boot.

However when I go to grub and I edit the boot options by erasing quiet and splash and adding `acpi=off`, ubuntu suddenly boots. (by the way nomodeset is there -by itself it does not change the booting problem)

I have multiple other problems but I want to understand why the above is happening

Comment: Does your system BIOS have anything about Advanced Power Saving?  If it does, try enabling it or disabling it in BIOS and see if that makes a difference.  ACPI stands for Advanced Configuration and Power Interface.

Comment: Ok thanks, I ll try that. First I have to solve a couple of other things more...

Comment: the options in ACPI settings (BIOS) are only Power LED blinking and CPU over temperature alert Auto. Nothing more